# Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, excel

I am trying to use the Excel File Dialog window from a asp.net page. it works good from my local computer but gives the following error on the server.

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>
> [COMException (0x80004005): Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.]
>      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.ApplicationClass.get_FileDialog(MsoFileDialogType fileDialogType) +0
>      FileMoverSetup.FileDirectorySetup.btnProcessedBrowse_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\psanders\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\FileMoverSetup\FileMoverSetup\FileDirectorySetup.aspx.cs:390
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9628722
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
>      System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>      System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
>      System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724

I have been working on this for days without any luck. any suggestions??

**EDIT**

This is what I am talking about. It works perfectly on my box but when I put it on the server it has the above error.

[image]

Comment: Where do you expect the dialog to be displayed in a web page? in the browser?

Comment: It is a pop up window to select a directory location. I am calling the excel folder dialog window to get a directory to populate a text box with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I received this response on  a different forum.

> ... and it never will.
>
> First, it only ever works on your DEV machine because everything, including the web server, is running as YOU on your desktop.
>
> When deployed on the server, everything runs as a service without any visible desktop. So, the dialog that shows up only shows up on the web server where nobody can see it. The dialog will NEVER show up on the client machine.
>
> Also, Excel Interop (what you're doing) can NOT be used in a web application for various reasons, like re-entrancy and multiple thread problems. It may work so long as one user at a time is using a function in the website but it will fall on its face and crash with the more users using the functions at the same time.
>
> from Dave Kreskowiak on code project

So I am going to try and find a new method of using/creating a folder selection dialog.